# Groß- und Kleinschreibung von "Funktionales Testen" im Satz

Tags: capitalization

Wenn ich den Fachbegriff [Funktionales Testen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funktionstest) mitten im Satz verwende, schreibe ich dann "funktionales" groß oder klein? Eigentlich ist es ja ein Adjektiv, aber andererseits bilden "Funktionales" und "Testen" eine Einheit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hier dürften die Duden-Regeln [88](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K88) und [89](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K89) greifen.

> **Regel 88:**
>
> 1. Alle zu einem mehrteiligen Namen gehörenden Adjektive, Partizipien, Pronomen und Zahlwörter schreibt man groß <§ 60>.
>
> Klein Dora, Friedrich der Große, der Große Kurfürst, der Alte Fritz, der Schiefe Turm von Pisa, die Ewige Stadt (Rom), der Große Bär (Sternbild), der Indische Ozean, das Kap der Guten Hoffnung, die Schwäbische Alb, Vereinigte Staaten von Amerika, Gasthaus zur Alten Post, Medizinische Klinik des Städtischen Krankenhauses Wiesbaden, Statistisches Bundesamt, Börsenverein des Deutschen Buchhandels, Institut für Deutsche Sprache
>
> [...]
>
> **Regel 89:**
>
> Es gibt Wortgruppen (feste Begriffe), die keine Namen sind, obwohl sie oft als Namen angesehen werden. Hier schreibt man die Adjektive in der Regel klein <§ 63>.
>
> - italienischer Salat
> - künstliche Intelligenz
> - das schwarze Schaf
> - das neue Jahr
> - die mittlere Reife
> - der olympische Gedanke
>
> [...]
>
> Adjektive, die mit dem folgenden Substantiv einen idiomatisierten Gesamtbegriff bilden, können großgeschrieben werden; die Kleinschreibung der Adjektive ist jedoch auch hier der Regelfall <§ 63 E>. Im fachsprachlichen Schreibgebrauch hat sich in einigen Fällen die Adjektivgroßschreibung verfestigt <§ 64 E>.
>
> - der letzte oder Letzte Wille
> - das zweite oder Zweite Gesicht
> - das gelbe oder Gelbe Trikot
> - die aktuelle oder Aktuelle Stunde
> - Vorwiegend in Großschreibung: die Erste Hilfe, die Große Kreisstadt
>
> [...]

Es liegt also bei Dir, zu entscheiden, ob "Funktionales Testen" ein *mehrteiliger Name*, nur eine *Wortgruppe, die kein Name ist, obwohl sie oft als Name angesehen wird* oder ein *idiomatisierter Gesamtbegriff* ist.

Mein Bauchgefühl würde hier von einem *idiomatisierten Gesamtbegriff* ausgehen, und insgesamt eher auf Kleinschreibung gehen.

Comment: Mmh, die Lage ist wohl nicht ganz eindeutig. So wird in Regel 89 explizit auf den fachsprachlichen Schreibgebrauch und die dortige (gelegentliche) Adjektivgroßschreibung verwiesen.

Comment: @MartinBurger Das stimmt, wobei ich da eher an medizinische und juristische Fachliteratur denke, die eine eigene deutsche Fachsprache haben. So weit sind wir IT-ler (glücklicherweise?) noch nicht. Aber ja, man könnte wohl auch eine Großschreibung verantworten.

Comment: Ah, Danke! Mittels Google konnte ich auf die schnelle keinen Mehrheitsentscheid erwirken, da wird mal klein, mal groß geschrieben. Werde dann auf Kleinschreibung umschwenken.

Comment: Ich glaube, §88 fällt aus. Mit Blick auf die Beispiele scheint mir sicher, dass _Name_ hier gemeint ist als ["kennzeichnende Benennung eines Einzelwesens, Ortes oder Dinges, durch die es von anderen seiner Art unterschieden wird; Eigenname"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Name_Ruf_Benennung_Bezeichnung#Bedeutung2a)

Answer (score 1):

Vor dem Lesen Jans kompetenter Antwort kam ich für mich zu folgendem Schluß:

Wenn der Charakter als Eigenname betont werden soll würde ich zur Großschreibung tendieren:

- wir suchen einen Fachmann für Funktionales Testen
- die Abteilung hatte kein Buch zu Funktionalem Testen vorrätig

Im allgemeinen Sprachfluß würde ich es kleinschreiben:

- Der siebte der funktionalen Tests ist gescheitert
- Wir arbeiten mit funktionalen und Akzeptanz-Tests.

Comment: "Wir arbeiten mit funktionalen und Akzeptanz-Tests." Das war ziemlich genau der Fall, der mich zu dieser Frage brachte. Ich hätte es in diesem Fall allerdings groß geschrieben.

Comment: Geschrieben würde ich "Wir arbeiten mit funktionalen Tests und Akzeptanztests." tendieren, weil ein Adjektiv und ein kombiniertes Substantiv so schlecht gekürzt werden können - in mündlicher Rede allerdings scheint mir das Kürzen akzeptabel. Ungekürzt wiederum erscheint mir Großschreibung auch wieder akzeptabel.

Comment: Die amtlichen Regeln wurden kürzlich dahin gehend dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch angepasst, dass neben "funktionales Testen" auch "Funktionales Testen" erlaubt ist. Diese Antwort scheint mir die beste zu sein, weil sie die wirkliche Schreibpraxis genau skizziert. Es wäre zwar noch formal korrekt, es genau umgekehrt zu machen, aber das wäre doch sehr ungewöhnlich. "Funktionaler Test" befindet sich in der Grenzzone zwischen Adjektiv + Substantiv und zweiteiliger Name. Genau wie hier beschrieben, hat mal die eine, mal die andere Seite mehr Gewicht.